# NSXMLParser parse value based on element attribute

Tags: objective-c, nsxmlparser

I have XML sample:

```
<book id="bk101">
   <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
</book>
<book id="bk102">
   <title>Midnight Rain</title>
</book>
```

How can I output title value for book with id "bk101"?

My code:

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"book"])
    {
        NSString *codeValue = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"id"];

        if ([codeValue isEqualToString:@"bk101"]) {
            //NSLog(@"found"); // output book title here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please print attributeDict?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose **structure XML such as in the example** and  **tag has no child elements** and **text inside the tag does not have unicode or other special characters**. Then for output to console (for example) "title" value for book with id "bk101" you should:

1. Declare `codeValue` as property.

   ```
   @property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *codeValue;
   ```
2. Change your code like below:

   ```
   - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
   {
       if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"book"])
       {
         _codeValue = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"id"];
       }
   }
   ```
3. Add implementation `foundCharacters:` method like below:

   ```
   - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
   {
     if ([_codeValue isEqualToString:@"bk101"]) 
     {
       NSLog(@"found: %@", string); // output book title here
     }
   }
   ```
4. Add implementation `didEndElement:` method like below (selectively for the case where not all tags "book" will have an attribute):

   ```
   - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
   {
     if (_codeValue != nil) 
     {
       _codeValue = nil
     }
   }
   ```

NOTE: **If the conditions specified in the beginning of the post will be different - you may need a different implementation.**

As alternative you can use [XMLConverter](https://github.com/rsoldatenko/XMLConverter) and convert your XML (I did some changes):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<books>
  <book id="bk101">
    <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
  </book>
  <book id="bk102">
    <title>Midnight Rain</title>
  </book>
</books>
```

to `NSDictionary` like below:

```
2013-12-24 13:15:48.167 test[603:70b] {
    books =     {
        book =         (
                        {
                "-id" = bk101;
                title = "XML Developer's Guide";
            },
                        {
                "-id" = bk102;
                title = "Midnight Rain";
            }
        );
    };
}
```

and work with it.